# Java : Json String with ANSI escape code to Object

Tags: java, gson

I have the below String in Java,

```
String ansiStr = "{\"traceback\":[\"\\u001b[1;36m  File \\u001b[1;32m\\\"MyFile\\\"\\u001b[1;36m, line \\u001b[1;32m1\\u001b[0m\\n\\u001b[1;33m    codedata\\u001b[0m\\n\\u001b[1;37m                         ^\\u001b[0m\\n\\u001b[1;31mSyntax\\u001b[0m\\u001b[1;31m:\\u001b[0m EOF\\n\"],\"ename\":\"Error\",\"evalue\":\"UnExpected\"}";
```

The `String` is a reply from IPython kernel and looks like in JSon format and i tried the below code to parse it as an object,

```
ArrayList list = gson.fromJson(jsonString, ArrayList.class);
```

I get the following exception,

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
```

How can i convert this String in to a JSon object ? What should be the Class/Type ? I am stuck as it has ANSI color codes to it with **"["** symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
try {
        JSONObject object=new JSONObject(ansiStr);
        TrackBook track = new Gson().fromJson(object.toString(),TrackBook.class);
        List<String> trackList=track.getTraceback();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

TrackBook.java

```
public class TrackBook {
@SerializedName("traceback")
@Expose
private List<String> traceback = null;
@SerializedName("ename")
@Expose
private String ename;
@SerializedName("evalue")
@Expose
private String evalue;

public List<String> getTraceback() {
    return traceback;
}

public void setTraceback(List<String> traceback) {
    this.traceback = traceback;
}

public String getEname() {
    return ename;
}

public void setEname(String ename) {
    this.ename = ename;
}

public String getEvalue() {
    return evalue;
}

public void setEvalue(String evalue) {
    this.evalue = evalue;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to read your JSON as an `ArrayList`, but it's not an array - it's an object:

```
{
    "traceback": [...], // this is actually an array
    "ename": "Error",
    "evalue": "UnExpected"
}
```

And the error message you receive hints at it: `Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT`.

So all you need to do is to read it as a `Map`:

```
Map map = gson.fromJson(ansiStr, Map.class);
```

`Gson` will automatically detect that `traceback` is an array and create a `List` for it. You can test it like this:

```
System.out.println(((List) map.get("traceback")).get(0));
```